# Unblock an IP address on AWS LightSail

Tags: amazon-web-services, ssh, bitnami, amazon-lightsail

My website https://www.pinbargain.com is hosted on LightSail received some suspicious IP addresses, therefore, I followed this document
https://docs.bitnami.com/aws/faq/configuration/block-suspicious-ip/
to block some suspicious IP address
I use this command to block the IP address:

```
iptables -A INPUT -s 1.2.3.4 -j DROP
```

Now the problem is I accidentally blocked IP address from my Internal service. Therefore, I want to find the IP address I blocked and unlock them.

I have searched on docs.bitnami.com but I couldn't find the command to unblock.

Comment: This other post solves your question: https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/57471/181735

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I took a closer look at the article you sent (https://docs.bitnami.com/aws/faq/configuration/block-suspicious-ip/).

At the bottom, it says how to delete a rule (aka how to unblock an IP).

Basically, you would run this command (replace `1.2.3.4` with the IP):

```
iptables -D INPUT -s 1.2.3.4 -j DROP
```

I also found out how to see a list of blocked IPs by looking at the `help` menu:

```
iptables --list-rules
```

Also, don't forget to reboot.

Comment: Thank you. I saw that delete part as well. However, the problem is I don't know what IP addresses I have blocked. Therefore, I need to see all the IP addresses I blocked before doing the delete. This is not documented on the website. But yes,  your list command works. Thank you!